# how to set up a good structure for a dictionary in typescript?

Tags: typescript

i am currently planning to make some kind of a dictionary for fetched data from the internet in typescript.

the plan is to have an internal datastructure for example like this:

```
type Internal = {
    size: number,
    height : number
}
```

but then there are multiple sources where i fetch a json file with the same data, but different naming like

```
type External1 = {
    size1: number,
    height1 : number
}

type External2 = {
    size2: number,
    height2 : number
}
```

in the end i need some kind of an interface to be able to translate these objects / jsons into my internal datastructure.
What would be a good way to do something like that in typescript? since the external data can and will change its namings from time to time i am looking for a more or less flexible way.
any idea would be great!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to approach this; one thing you could do is write a helper function called `keyMapper()` which takes a mapping object from the keys of the source type (like `External1`) to the corresponding keys of the target type (like `Internal`), and produces another function which converts objects of the source type to objects of the target type. It could also give you a function that does the reverse transformation.

Here's one possible implementation of that:

```
function keyMapper<M extends Record<keyof M, K>, K extends PropertyKey>(map: M) {

  const revMap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(map).map(([k, v]) => [v, k])) as
    { [K in keyof M as M[K]]: K };
  type MRev = typeof revMap;

  return Object.assign(<T extends object>(t: T) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(t).map(([k, v]) => [k in map ? map[k as keyof M] : k, v])
  ) as { [K in keyof T as K extends keyof M ? M[K] : K]: T[K] }, {
    reverse: <T extends object>(t: T) => Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(t).map(([k, v]) => [k in revMap ? revMap[k as keyof MRev] : k, v])
    ) as { [K in keyof T as K extends keyof MRev ? Extract<MRev[K], PropertyKey> : K]: T[K] }
  })
}
```

I don't know if it's worth going over that implementation in excruciating detail.  Highlights are:

- it uses [the `Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [the `Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) methods to convert objects to and from arrays of their entries.  Arrays of entries are nice because you can use [the `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform them.
- the typings for this function involve a lot of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) over which we use [key remapping in mapped types via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). Key remapping in mapped types represents at the type level what we are doing by remapping keys with `Object.toEntries(Object.entries(...).map(...))` at the value level.
- the implementation has several [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that what we are doing is okay.  The type checker is essentially unable to understand generic conditional mapped type manipulation, so asserting types lets us avoid compiler errors.  That means we need to be careful that we implemented it properly, because the compiler is unable to verify that for us.

---

Let's try it out:

```
let internal: Internal;

const fromExternal1 = keyMapper({ size1: "size", height1: "height" });
internal = fromExternal1({ size1: 123, height1: 456 });
console.log(internal) // {size: 123, height: 456}    

const external1: External1 = fromExternal1.reverse(internal);
console.log(external1) // {size1: 123, height1: 456}

const fromExternal2 = keyMapper({ size2: "size", height2: "height" });
internal = fromExternal2({ size2: 456, height2: 789 });
console.log(internal) // {size: 456, height: 789}

const external2: External2 = fromExternal2.reverse(internal);
console.log(external2) // {size2: 456, height2: 789}
```

Looks good.  We have a `fromExternal1()` function that converts `External1` objects into `Internal` objects.  Additionally, `fromExternal1.reverse()` converts `Internal` objects back into `External1` objects.  And the same goes for `External2`.  If the keys of one of these types changes, you just have to change the appropriate entry in the argument you pass to `keyMapper()`.

---

Note that this might be a little too generic for your tastes; the `fromExternal1()` function doesn't actually require that its input be an `External1`.  It will accept any object type and perform the transformation into some other type:

```
const hmm = fromExternal1({ a: "abc", b: 123, size1: true });
/* const hmm: { a: string; b: number; size: boolean; } */
console.log(hmm); // {a: "abc", b: 123, size: true}
```

That accurately represents what the function does, but maybe you'd prefer to restrict it.  To do so, you could just copy `fromExternal1` and `fromExternal1.reverse` to new variables of a less forgiving type:

```
const ex1ToInt: (ex1: External1) => Internal = fromExternal1; // okay
const intToEx1: (int: Internal) => External1 = fromExternal1.reverse; // okay

ex1ToInt({ a: "abc", b: 123, size1: true }); // error!
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJIAuAnjMgJLBkQBOoGSAvHiaUlAJZYQAXEmABXMACMmAGi6kAFhF4BzeWWFjJTLgF8iXStSQBRAB4NmmAIztOhbj34QrG8VMaz73RSrUuRbtpeesRehshmFiwATLYEXqR8AtGuWh5ySD6qZCkBabr6XgD0RZkQGNSMSABmosDwZLwA9sCFpLX1jS1IANYQFACyIDCVADwDSBDmEMAAJlBIAEoQ8E2Ms6N9FE3VSAPSSADSAHwHh5PTcwsACoxNlZSH-ccAFGDDwgMAlHYZq8BQMhIRgQABuQxgtgA8hIAFYrMgAOmqdzAxnojF40BeMPhDURMzImOx7xgX0RpJeLwA2j0DqCALo-NjHJDU0EHHpMn4gKAZUi4NnnXjAXr9HZ7JC8vbUw4MhnCc46ADcGXCe2WoNs4QlIPBw1VoQcILIomYSFxCMRvL4ymAL1GABULgwrkgmnCEa91EhHczWZb8SimmiMVioC9+RbPfjCcSI2RyZSaXSkIz-WyekgRUhSUgAPy54a0qULLYSgYMpDCVPpjI8haC2XZ0Xl3bO6XnKau+Zi7a7CaFgayquKhW+kdIHQHeIOUh6phQIRIJ0uma9j14sje4R+9gBmNI4OhonhyMJOeBpFxs+JinDKm0+lM-eZlvAsEQgsf-UwEvStsNTBUdemfL4owbPAhXfQCOwWLtLl7QCBk1b9IkYBAyHGTURwOW57iYR5nmrI5x0dScQgcHRwOCQo6K8DAICBEUokwYQ6FYjBDS4f5ARqVFIiYFgbA4LYIUqF5BSSZxhAAImk2SDiyPw5OUshZKnL5DVIFihMwWxj0EywMCsSTHAEfwrGiABmJSlGyfwABYAFYADZNO0pBeKaRjEQwJplBeXTjJ+Eo8Gk4QrNsspfB9FzXJ0Bw2i8lo+O7PSTOEIzhIMgTpmMqxEQXRglyC+gMq0njUp8iA-ICl50oK0LSlwaTLJsuzYqctyQiqgEgUM-KYlsMThgkqSnFyeSnEUmLsimtSNOozzgpYXKQ2yzBojM6Tcnizr5uEAB2AAOABODy+qgGq6sC1bMGa8KnGEfa5rUY7zt6rxeKBRqYiyoatvWtFAYwaIirBRcIDKzjKu+6rfP8wK-q2x7Wsml63IOtRclOs6vtIH7MjAMBgc2kyzJAOSQAkeBZokSKOvMmTyEYURkGWrgigAKhS-ribAYRBSpnhT2AZRlSQBm8ncSWIqlpoapAYBJcS7miium6kZeeQSa0pAwtwEXZJpumDmlqKDnlol2YJvm0tMKxHSaDjhAax2Ac4qwMw4jKydBqxJbCpoehACgkCu5j6Gdsx-Bh9jypC19yZE-iNoDiHQShoPShDsPkqmJ2XfoSnqdp+nGeitrhBtjn9bCpg7kYABCei28IHQgA)